# Acorn Archimedes 420/1

Tags: display, connection

I have an old Acorn computer which I am sure works fine but the monitor gave up years ago. It has a 9 pin analogue RGB port. Any suggestions on getting a monitor that will work with it?

Comment: Just a FYI. look at http://acorn.chriswhy.co.uk/ for some info on your old computer a couple of links and this link http://acorn.chriswhy.co.uk/docs/Acorn/AN/249.pdf for info on monitors.

Comment: An Amiga monitor should work fine with it, IIRC, but finding one of those would be nearly as difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll have a look and see what I can find - otherwise I will just put it on eBay and see if there are any takers!

Answer (score 5):

It's complicated and depends on the model. You might be unlucky with the 420. This article explains: http://www.riscos.org/legacy/monitors.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll have a look - otherwise I will just put it on eBay and see if there are any takers!

Comment: I have it on good authority you can rewire a SCART connector to use it with a TV. Details are here: [link](http://www.acornelectron.co.uk/eug/66/a-scar.html)